# On subgroups of the form $HZ(G)$ where $H$ is abelian subgroup of non-abelian group $G$ such that $H \rlap{\;\,/}\subseteq Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, group-isomorphism

Let $H$ be a an abelian subgroup of a non-abelian group $G$ such that $H \rlap{\;\,/}\subseteq Z(G) Z(G)$ ; then I can prove that $HZ(G)$ is an abelian subgroup such that $Z(G) \subset HZ(G) \subset G$ ; also if $H$ is normal then so is $HZ(G)$ as $gHZ(G)g^{-1} \subseteq gHg^{-1} Z(G) \subseteq HZ(G)$ ; I would like to know when are two subgroups $H_1Z(G) $ ; $H_2Z(G)$ isomorphic ? or more generally when are $H_1Z(G_1) $ ; $H_2Z(G_2)$ isomorphic given $G_1,G_2$ is isomorphic ( here $H_1$ a subgroup of $G_1$ , $H_2$ a subgroup of $G_2$ ) ?

Comment: $\;H\le Z(G)\implies \;H\lhd G\;$  , so the "if $\;H\;$ is normal..." condition is superfluous.

Comment: @Timbuc: Sorry but I have assumed that $H$ is not contained in $Z(G)$ , please read again

Comment: @Timbuc: Ok , I didn't know how to write that , edited

Comment: I am not sure is this is a very meaningful question. What sort of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @Derek Holt : What conditions on $H_1,H_2$ ensure that $H_1Z(G)$  and $H_2Z(G)$ are isomorphic ?

Comment: The only such condition I can think of is that they are both of the same prime order. Otherwise they could have different intersections with $Z(G)$. I still think you need to be clearer about the kind of conditions you are looking for.